# Real meaning of nanigenai 「何気ない」?

Tags: words

I translated into google translate and the meaning is casual. What "casual" things that suit with this word? Is this word means "merely" ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means casual in the sense of.. casual, unconcerned, without much attention. However, I believe it would not be used for "casual" when referring to look or clothes.

Consider the following sample sentences:

> 1. 何気なく言った言葉も誰かを傷つけることがある。

*Even a casual remark could hurt someone's feelings.*

> 2. 彼女はその本に何気なく目をやった。

*The girl had a casual glance at the book.*

Do the above example clarify the meaning?

You can also check this page on [weblio](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E4%BD%95%E6%B0%97%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84) for some other examples.